# Jquery Sliders wont work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use Timepicker - its an addon for jquery `http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/` this addon requires sliders to work.

for some reason i just cannot get sliders to work - i managed to get normal jquery ui datapicker to work but cannot make slider work.

here is my current code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/plugins/groupon_cart/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/plugins/groupon_cart/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/plugins/groupon_cart/js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/plugins/groupon_cart/js/jquery.ui.slider.js"></script>
```

I've checked the address and they work. 
By the way i also tried without including the `jquery.ui.slider.js.`

I do the following in bottom of page:

```
 <div id="slider"></div>

 <script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {

    $j(function() {
        $j( "#slider" ).slider();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try this, you should reference jQuery, not the actual noConflict call.

`jQuery.noConflict();
var $j = jQuery;
$j(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: Tried - ddnt work Thanks for trying though

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the [Timepicker website](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/):

You also need to include jQuery and jQuery UI with datepicker and slider wigits. You should include them in your page **in the following order**:

- jQuery
- jQueryUI (with datepicker and slider wigits)
- Timepicker

Comment: Yea and i change it after you mentioned it. and nothing, beside if that was the problem how come jquery ui - normal datapicker works?

Comment: No idea, any chance you can share the url this resides on? would simplify aiding you remarkably

Comment: Well its in admin panel of wordpress, i would share otherwise.